# For which groups $G$ there is an integer $n$ with this property?

Tags: group-theory, modules, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group and $M$ be a finitely generated $ZG$-module. By a retract of $M$, I mean a submodule $N$ of $M$ for which there is a homomorphisms $f:M\to N$ such that $fi=id_N$, where $i$ is the inclusion.

My question is that for which groups $G$ there is an integer $n$ such that for every chain  $\cdots \subset   M_3 \subset M_2 \subset M_1 \subseteq M$ of retracts of $M$, we have $M_i =M_n$ for all $i\geq n$? Can we find such an $n$ for free groups of finite ranks?

For example, If $G=1$, then $M$ be a finitely generated abelian groups and $n$ can be the number of direct summands in the canonical form of $M$.

Comment: In your definition of retract you don't want f to be the inclusion?

Comment: In your final paragraph, I think you meant to write "the canonical form of $M$"?

Comment: Also, does your analysis of the case $G=1$ extend to all finite groups $G$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, but they imply the same definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher You are right. I've made a mistake. I'll edit it.

Comment: @LeeMosher Unfortunately I don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

For finite groups I believe this is still true.

In the case $G=1$, all that you are using is that every finitely generated $\mathbb ZG$-module is also a finitely generated abelian group.

But that fact remains true if $G$ is a finite group, for the following reasons. Let $\{m_1,...,m_K\} \subset M$ be a finite generating set for $M$ as a $\mathbb ZG$ module. Enumerating $G=\{g_1,...,g_L\}$, it follows that $\{g_l \cdot m_k \mid l=1,\ldots,L, \, k=1,\ldots,K\}$ is a finite generating set for $M$ as an abelian group. So once again, one may use the number of direct summands of $M$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have a question: As you told, $\{g_l \cdot m_k \mid l=1,\ldots,L, \, k=1,\ldots,K\}$ is a finite generating set for $M$ as an abelian group. So can we conclude that $\{g_l \cdot m_k \mid l=1,\ldots,L, \, k=1,\ldots,K\}$ is a finite generating set for $M$ as $\mathbb{Z}G$-module?

Comment: Well, yes, you could conclude that, although there's not much to that conclusion. One is already assuming that $\{m_k \mid k=1,...,K\} = \{1 \cdot m_k \mid k=1,...,K\}$ is a $\mathbb ZG$ module generating set, so any larger subset, such as $\{g_l \cdot m_k \mid l=1,...,L, \, k=1,...,K\}$ is also a $\mathbb ZG$ module generating set.

Comment: Dear @LeeMohser , I got completely. Thank you very much for your nice explanation and your help.